# stack build works as expected but stack runghc can't find local modules

Tags: haskell, import, haskell-stack

So I have a Haskell project (managed using stack) structured like this:

```
.
├── Main.hs
├── Other1.hs
├── subfolder
    └── Other2.hs
```

where the `Main` module imports both `Other1` and `Other2`, as simply as

```
import Other1
import Other2
```

My `.cabal` file says:

```
name: (...)

executable Main
hs-source-dirs:
  .,
  subfolder
main-is: Main.hs
other-modules:
  Other1
  Other2
```

Now, if I run `stack build` everything works great, all modules are compiled and it looks like nothing can go wrong. But then if I try to execute my program with `stack runghc Main`, module `Other2` (the one in the subfolder) is not found.

Why is that the case? How can I execute my code?

Comment: `stack exec Main`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that `stack exec Main` yields `Executable named Main not found on path...` (even though `stack build` says that it in fact installing `executable Main in ` one of the paths checked by `stack exec`